# Final project ideas - computational geometry

Tags: soft-question, computational-geometry

Next semester I am teaching (the programming part) of a course in **Computational Geometry**. There are 14 weeks of class, two "pure theory/blackboard" hours per week, one "theory/blackboard exercises" hour per week and one "computer lab" hour per week.

My intention for the "computer lab" sessions is that the students work (almost from day one) on a **programming project** that they can submit at the end of the course. My thoughts for the structure and evaluation of the projects are more or less the same than in [this link](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Etaoju/cse546/finalprojects.htm). To sum up: students can either design a graphical applet that illustrates some algorithm, work on an open problem or develop an application of Computational Geometry to other areas.

However, I am not an expert in Computational Geometry and I **would like you to give me some suggestions of interesting topics for the final projects**.

Let me give some context for the level of the projects:

- The students are 4th-year (that's **last year** in Spain) **undergraduates in Mathematics**. Their programming background is a two-semester course on basic programming in Python and two one-semester courses on Numerical Analysis where they did some programming in Matlab. Some of them have a wider background and a small fraction of them are also last-year Computer Science undergraduates.
- The **textbook** we are going to follow is: [A Short Course in Computational Geometry and Topology](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319059563) by H. Edelsbrunner. (The theory professor chose it).

In previous years this course has been Machine-Learning-oriented, so I might also suggest some projects related with ML.

Comment: You may also ask questions like this at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [The Open Problems Project](https://topp.openproblem.net/) has grown a bit
out-of-date, we recently moved it to github to improve updating.
Because it was "originally aimed to record important open problems of interest to researchers in computational geometry and related fields," it has a slant
appropriate for your purposes.

A typical problem is this, proposed by
[R. Nandakumar](https://mathoverflow.net/users/142600/nandakumar-r):

- [Problem 67: Fair Partitioning of Convex Polygons](https://topp.openproblem.net/p67).

[image]

Figure from: Bárány, Imre, Pavle Blagojević, and András Szűcs. "Equipartitioning by a convex 3-fan." *Advances in Mathematics* 223, no. 2 (2010): 579-593.
[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2009.08.016).

Comment: Incidentally, I also teach a project-based course on Computational Geometry.